# Comma delimited string into an array but only numeric values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

There is an string like

```
1,36,42,43,45,69,Standard,Executive,Premium
```

I want to convert it in array but need only numeric values as

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 36
   [2] => 42
   [3] => 43
   [4] => 45
   [5] => 69
)
```

Not all string value in array.

Comment: What you have try so far?

Comment: show your code with the problem statement.

Comment: need to insert only numeric values in table

Comment: It's `array_filter`

Comment: i got string from a table column and need insert into only numeric to another table column

Comment: @u_mulder pls write some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and short solution using `array_filter`, `explode` and `is_numeric` functions:

```
$str = "1,36,42,43,45,69,Standard,Executive,Premium";
$numbers = array_filter(explode(",", $str), "is_numeric");

print_r($numbers);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 36
    [2] => 42
    [3] => 43
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 69
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: just use straight up `array_filter(explode(',', $str), 'is_numeric')`, no need for that anonymous

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r(array_filter(
    explode(',', '1,36,42,43,45,69,Standard,Executive,Premium'),
    'ctype_digit'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array('1','36','42','43','45','69','Standard','Executive','Premium');
foreach($array as $value) if (is_integer($value)) $new_array[] = $value;

print_r($new_array);
?>
```

[EDIT] oh yeah I actually prefer your version RomanPerekhrest & u_mulder :p

Answer (score 0):

Have a look attached snippet:

Please have a look Demo : https://eval.in/593963

```
<?php
$c="1,36,42,43,45,69,Standard,Executive,Premium";
$arr=explode(",",$c);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    if (!is_numeric($value)) { 
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($arr);

?>
```

Output:

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 36
    [2] => 42
    [3] => 43
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 69
    [6] => Standard
    [7] => Executive
    [8] => Premium
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 36
    [2] => 42
    [3] => 43
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 69
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tra this:

```
$string = "1,36,42,43,45,69,Standard,Executive,Premium";
print_r(array_filter(explode(',', $string), 'is_numeric'));
```